# RJ45 ethernet stick

Tags: microcontroller, microchip

Does any kind of *RJ45 sticks* exists? By *RJ 45 stick*, I mean anything that contains electronics and is small enough to be supported only by the RJ45 connector itself... and connects to the network.

Can I build such a stick myself? I would need a special chip for that purpose, as it is beyond my capabilities(and space requirements) to start from a generic processor. Also I do **not** want the huge(for this) and overly complicated(for this) [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) with [ethernet shield](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoEthernetShield).

Here is a mockup of my wish:

**(it is just wishful thinking - I will settle for much less)**
[image: RJ45 stick]

Features:

- Connects with DHCP
- Power via POE or cable
- Responds to http requests
- Can be programmed
- LEDs
- TTL cable optional

Can be used for:

- Instant web server
- Indicator(led) for anything that is going on on the network (is xx up and running)
- Start your coffee maker over the Internet (connect to relay)

Comment: If you haven't found what you're looking for, then you haven't used google yet.  There are any number of what you're looking for available for a few tens of $'s.

Comment: There are lots of devices that function as you describe, but there's no real reason to physically package them in a "stick" format, because the whole point of Ethernet is to support remote connections, just like the whole point of USB is to support local connections.

Comment: @markt: I have googled! I have spend many hours, and not once have I seen anything like this. Can you show me a picture or a page with such a product?

Comment: @Dave Tweed: What do you mean by remote connection? The stick format is perfect to bring in your pocket and connect wherever you need, what it is programmed for.

Comment: ... and that's why sticks use USB connectors, not Ethernet connectors. You can also get Bluetooth and WiFi-based devices. Why do you want Ethernet in particular?

Comment: USB always has 5V available, at at least 100mA, but Ethernet does not, since PoE is not always implemented, so you are less likely to find what you want in this form factor. Have you considered [Plug Computers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug_computer) such as SheevaPlug/DreamPlug/TonidoPlug? PoE is 44V so would require conversion to 5V in the stick.

Comment: Android sticks, with usb-otg support and a usb to ethernt adaptor. Some wire hacking and you can get poe with a simple switching regulator. Some can do pure linux builds too. Or just use the wifi.

Comment: @dave the whole point of ethernet is to support a network connection, period.

Comment: @Passerby: Don't blame me! I'm just explaining why the OP isn't finding the devices he seeks in the market -- there's no demand for them. You can walk up to a random computer and plug in a USB device and get connectivity and power. You can't get power out of the Ethernet port on a computer (or on most hubs, for that matter).

Comment: @hans just checking online, there are tiny android and linux computers with ethernet built in as well. So the only hack is adding a poe to 5v regulator.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like [Ethernet Module](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/765) with a [Teensy 3.1](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/teensy31.html) might be what you are looking for. I haven't actually worked on something like this. But if you find this helpful please let me know. Now even I would like to do something like that.

Comment: Looks promising - I will look at it tomorrow. Just now, I can not see the size!? -and wether it can be programmed through ethernet!?

Comment: Teensy 3.1 has a size of approximately 4cmX2cm. No, it can not be programmed through Ethernet. But you can program it in such a way that it can do predefined operations depending on the input from Ethernet.

Comment: Ideally you wouldn't need to add a microcontroller, as typical ethernet bridge modules have one inside, but perhaps not user reprogrammable, so the question becomes if it's factory command set is sufficient.

Comment: @chris the enc module only does the phy/mac part, it needs a microcontroller with a tcpip stack and everything. The wiznet parts are better, as is the xport. Some ethernet to serial adaptors as well.